# If $(-\Delta_x)^{-1}f(x,t)$ is jointly continuous in $(x,t)$, then is $t \to \int \lvert f(x,t) \rvert^2 dx$ at least $L^\infty$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

This question was originally [posted in ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738565/if-delta-x-1fx-t-is-jointly-continuous-in-x-t-then-is-t-to-in/4738720?noredirect=1#comment10048646_4738720).

Let me rephrase the question:

Let $f(x,t) \in L^2\bigl([0,1]^2 \times [0,1] \bigr)$ which is "everywhere defined" on $[0,1]^2 \times [0,1]$ and $\int_{[0,1]^2} f(x,t) d^2x=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Then, we can apply the inverse Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{-1}_x$ to this $f(x,t)$ to see that
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta)^{-1}_xf(x,t) \in H^2_xL^2_t ([0,1]^2 \times [0,1] \bigr)
\end{equation}
That is, $\int_0^1 \lVert (-\Delta)^{-1}f(\cdot, t) \rVert_{H^2_x}^2 dt < \infty$.

Now, let us further assume that $(-\Delta)^{-1}_xf(x,t)$ is in fact $\textit{jointly}$ continuous with respect to $(x,t)$ on $[0,1]^2 \times [0,1]$.

Then, I wonder if
\begin{equation}
t \to \lVert f(\cdot, t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2= \int_{[0,1]^2} \lvert f(x,t) \rvert^2 d^2x
\end{equation}
is a "bounded" function of $t \in [0,1]$ or at least belongs to $L^\infty_t[0,1]$.

The counterexample in the above link at least does not contradict boundedness of $t \to \lVert f(\cdot, t) \rVert_{L^2_x}^2$.

I tried to approximate $f(x,t)$ by functions of the form $g(x)h(t)$ but this does not seem to work well.. Could anyone please help me?